# How to Secure non-logged in user web pages?

Tags: security, authentication, oauth, authorization, jwt

I have been reading about securing REST APIs and have read about oAuth and JWTs. Both are really great approaches, but from what I have understood, they both work after a user is authenticated or in other words "logged in".

However, what about the web pages that are accessed without user authentication? Is there a way to protect them? are there any best practices to secure non-authenticated web pages?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by securing the web-pages?

Comment: Well you can use https to secure non-authenticated web pages

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Client Credential Flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4) if a Resource Owner (User) is not involved. Read about it [here](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Client-Credentials-flow)